# manipulate the type byte in python3

Tags: python-3.x

Could you please help me to get the id of the report from this bytes?

```
b'{
"message":"The report with id 9520 was created but it is invalid!", 
"violations":"{\\"schemaLocation\\":\\"#\\",\\"pointerToViolation\\":\\"#\\",\\"causingExceptions\\":[{\\"schemaLocation\\":\\"#\\",\\"pointerToViolation\\":\\"#\\",\\"causingExceptions\\":[],\\"keyword\\":\\"required\\",\\"message\\":\\"required key [reportType] not found\\"},{\\"schemaLocation\\":\\"#\\",\\"pointerToViolation\\":\\"#\\",\\"causingExceptions\\":[],\\"keyword\\":\\"required\\",\\"message\\":\\"required key [finishedAt] not found\\"},{\\"schemaLocation\\":\\"#/properties/hosts/items\\",\\"pointerToViolation\\":\\"#/hosts/0\\",\\"causingExceptions\\":[],\\"keyword\\":\\"required\\",\\"message\\":\\"required key [applications] not found\\"}],\\"message\\":\\"3 schema violations found\\"}",    
"valid":false
}'
```

Comment: what is format of this input ? is json or string ?

Comment: This is a response.content of an request.post so a json

Comment: Give output of this data = resp.json()  from your resonse.content

Comment: this is solved thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't clearly  mentioned the all possible inputs.However, for the given input the below program is going to work! This is kinda hard coded!

```
import json

data=b'{"message":"The report with id 9520 was created but it is invalid!", "violations":"{\\"schemaLocation\\":\\"#\\",\\"pointerToViolation\\":\\"#\\",\\"causingExceptions\\":[{\\"schemaLocation\\":\\"#\\",\\"pointerToViolation\\":\\"#\\",\\"causingExceptions\\":[],\\"keyword\\":\\"required\\",\\"message\\":\\"required key [reportType] not found\\"},{\\"schemaLocation\\":\\"#\\",\\"pointerToViolation\\":\\"#\\",\\"causingExceptions\\":[],\\"keyword\\":\\"required\\",\\"message\\":\\"required key [finishedAt] not found\\"},{\\"schemaLocation\\":\\"#/properties/hosts/items\\",\\"pointerToViolation\\":\\"#/hosts/0\\",\\"causingExceptions\\":[],\\"keyword\\":\\"required\\",\\"message\\":\\"required key [applications] not found\\"}],\\"message\\":\\"3 schema violations found\\"}","valid":false}'


data = json.loads(data)["message"].split()
```

`data` is a list containing the values of the `message` key! You can index it to get the required value!

```
>>> data
['The', 'report', 'with', 'id', '9520', 'was', 'created', 'but', 'it', 'is', 'invalid!']
```